# Фигура в фигуре. Как такое сделать?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Фигура в фигуре. Как такое сделать?

[image: фигура в фигуре]

Comment: Я насчитал десять обычных треугольников, о какой «фигуре в фигуре» речь?

Comment: (с дубликатом по-моему слегка перестарались, не факт что автору нужен d3.js и вообще интерактив)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Икосаэдр в svg

> Не применялся векторный редактор

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      svg{
        width: 320px;
      }
      .path{
        stroke: #111111;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,300 66,127 200,22z" fill="#cdfaa8" class="path"/>
  <path d="M200,22 530,128 393,18z" fill="#2ea0e8" class="path"/>
  <path d="M200,22 530,128 288,302z" fill="#99d1ff" class="path"/>
  <path d="M200,22 288,302 0,300z" fill="#fefee2" class="path"/>
  <path d="M288,302 0,300 205,580z" fill="#fba76d" class="path"/>
  <path d="M288,302 205,580 533,472z" fill="#90334e" class="path"/>
  <path d="M288,302 533,472 531,128z" fill="#544cb0" class="path"/>
  <path d="M531,128 600,297 533,473z" fill="#35355f" class="path"/>
  <path d="M0,300 68,473 205,580z" fill="#ca622e" class="path"/>
  <path d="M205,580 533,473 399,577z" fill="#543030" class="path"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' у меня в самый интересный момент выключили свет....а у меня все девайсы от wifi

Comment: @MaximLensky Очень красивое решение )

Comment: @Кузьма наверно на css это сделать сложно или не возможно ..